# Singularity Confinement For Differential-Difference Systems

Tags: reference-request, differential-equations, integrable-systems

This is a follow-up question to an old question on this site ([link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23475/what-is-exactly-the-singularity-confinement-property)) which has a solution that describes the singularity confinement property for discrete systems.

Are there any papers or books that discuss this property for differential-difference equations?